# What does matrices act on different spaces mean in QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, group-theory, representation-theory

I have a Dirac kinetic term in a Lagrangian.

$$ i\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu D_\mu\psi
 = i\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\psi
 + g\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi A^a_\mu T^a,$$

However, I usually heard that people say that:

> $\gamma_{\mu}$ and $T^a$
>   are both matrices, but they act in different spaces and are not multiplied with each other as matrices.
>   They therefore commute with each other.

What does this sentence mean? On what spaces are they acting on? In the case of $SU(3)$, I know $T^a$ is a $3\times3$ matrix, how should I understand this "multiplication" in the Lagrangian term?

Another question I don't understand is that for example, I know how $SU(2)$ acts on a doublet and $U(1)$ acts on a field. How should I understand the multiplication of $SU(2)\times U(1)$ with a doublet? I have little knowledge of Group theory.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example of how operators act in different spaces and then commute is a quantum mechanical two-particle system, A and B. A (non-entangled) state will be the following:

$$\left | \psi \right > = \left | A \right > \times \left | B \right >$$

A operator $O_1$ acting on the first particle is actually $O^A_1 \times I^B$, and $O_2$ acting on the second particle is $I^A \times O^B_2$. A product of these operators acting on the state will be:

$$(O^A_1 \times I^B) (I^A \times O^B_2) (\left | A \right > \times \left | B \right >) = (I^A \times O^B_2) (O^A_1 \times I^B) (\left | A \right > \times \left | B \right >) = (O^A_1 \left | A \right >) \times (O^B_2 \left | B \right >)$$

In the same way, $\gamma$ and $T$ are operators in different spaces, so they act on the full state of the system as $\gamma_\mu \times I_2$ and $I_1 \times T^a$.

Multiplication of elements of different groups can be understood in the following way: (using a field and a doublet as an example)

Let $\phi$ be a field and $\begin{pmatrix}A\\B\end{pmatrix}$ a doublet; then, we REPRESENT then "simply multiplied" in the doublet, as indicated: $\left | \psi \right > = \begin{pmatrix} {\psi A} \\ \psi B\end{pmatrix}$; but this is just a notation, we have to take care, because $\phi$ and $(A, B)$ transforms differently. This is not just a doublet as before.

If T acts on the field and $R_\theta$ is the rotation operator on the doublet, we would have:

$$T R_\theta \left | \psi \right > = R_\theta T \left | \psi \right > = \begin{pmatrix} T(\psi) \cdot (Acos\theta + Bsin\theta) \\ T(\psi) \cdot (-Asin\theta + Bcos\theta) \end{pmatrix}$$

Note that this is exactly the same thing as the cross-product notation above, in my quantum mechanical example. Different operators act on different parts of our full state. $T$ is, in fact, $T \times I_{doublet}$, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

What it means is that our Lagrangian lives in the *direct product space*. In particular, the standard model space is

$$
SM = P \times SU(3)_c \times U(1)_{Y} \times SU(2)_L
$$

where $P$ stands for the poincare group. The "$\times$" symbol means that each of these spaces is separate, and doesn't talk to one another.

As a consequence, any representation of these spaces (i.e. matrices) completely commute, since if they didn't then they would somehow "know" about one another.

Comment: Can you give an example of doing multiplication in direct product space in QFT? An explicit example will be of great help to me!

Comment: It's usually not done explicitly, but a tractable and useful example would to be to derive the spin addition law from the states $2 \otimes 2$ reps in usual quantum mechanics

Comment: To do this you'll use something called the Kronecker product